# liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException: Cannot find parser that supports

Tags: java, docker, liquibase, java-17

I am encountering an error while running Liquibase with the following message: "Cannot find parser that supports db-upgrade/liquibase/auth-server/db.changelog-master.yaml". This happened after I changed my base image from java8 to java17.
error:

```
[2023-07-06T20:58:47.482Z] Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot find parser that supports db-upgrade/liquibase/auth-server/db.changelog-master.yaml

[2023-07-06T20:58:47.482Z] For more information, please use the --logLevel flag

[2023-07-06T20:58:47.482Z] [2023-07-06 20:58:47] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot find parser that supports db-upgrade/liquibase/auth-server/db.changelog-master.yaml

[2023-07-06T20:58:47.482Z] liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException: Cannot find parser that supports db-upgrade/liquibase/auth-server/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

```
# args:
#   change_log_file [required]
#   extra args (eg. JVM args) [optional]
function liquibase {
    java \
        -Dliquibase.scan.packages=${LIQUIBASE_PACKAGES_SCAN} \
        $2 \
        -jar ${LIQUIBASE_JAR} \
        --url=${URL} \
        --username=${USERNAME} \
        --password=${PASSWORD} \
        --driver=${DRIVER} \
        --classpath=${DRIVER_JAR}:${LIQUIBASE_SESSION_LOCK_JAR} \
        --changeLogFile=$1 \
        --logLevel=${LOG_LEVEL} \
        update
    return $?
}
```

```
  echo "INFO: Running the auth-server specific upgrade..."
    liquibase "db-upgrade/liquibase/auth-server/db.changelog-master.yaml"
    AUTH_SERVER_STATUS=$?
    if [[ "${AUTH_SERVER_STATUS}" == 0 ]]; then
        echo "INFO: Finished running the auth-server specific upgrade."
    else
        echo "ERROR: Running the auth-server liquibase scripts failed, see above for details; exiting"
        exit 4
```

Another changelog can run successfully, but it is a `.xml` file
 `liquibase "db-upgrade/liquibase/portal-data/portaldb-changelogs/portaldb-master-changelog.xml" "-Dapim_tenant_id=${TSSG_TENANT_ID}" PORTAL_DATA_STATUS=$?`

fix the liquibase.exception.UnknownChangelogFormatException

Comment: Which version of liquibase are you using?

Comment: @tgdavies version 4.3.5